# In Java, is there a String that is not equal to itself? When will str.equals(str) be False?

Tags: java

Could there be a string that
`str.equals(str)` is False?

Or in another way:

```
if(!str.equals(str)){
    System.out.println("-1");
}
```

Is there any way that the `println` line of code gets covered by a test?

Comment: Should be impossible since the first check is whether the object is the same before going through the string comparison https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585573/how-does-default-equals-implementation-in-java-works-for-string

Comment: I suppose you could try [monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42139413/1270789) and change the [`hashCode()` API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11656642/1270789) to return random values. This would most likely have the additional side-effect of breaking everything, though...

Comment: @ken-y-n no first checks for equality https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l974

Comment: You cannot replace ("monkey-patch") `String` from user code.  And changing `hashCode` wouldn't work anyway because `String.equals` doesn't call `String.hashCode`.  To change the behavior of `String.equals`, you would need to modify the Java codebase and build a custom JVM.   But frankly there is no good reason to do what the OP is asking / suggesting anyway.

Comment: @StephenC I'm glad, I suppose, that my random idea would never work! "But frankly there is no good reason to do what the OP is asking / suggesting anyway." I felt this was more a theoretical question, like how `NaN != NaN` in the floating-point world.

Comment: The answer to the theoretical question is a simple No.  If you tweak the behavior of `String` then it is not Java (tm) anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there couldn't. Here's the source code in java 17. As you can see, when the two objects are the same, the `equals` method always return `true`.

```java
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    return (anObject instanceof String aString)
            && (!COMPACT_STRINGS || this.coder == aString.coder)
            && StringLatin1.equals(value, aString.value);
}
```